# Trying to install LTTng on Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian Jessie (Debian)

Tags: raspberry-pi3, debian-based, lttng

I'm trying to install LTTng on a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspian Jessie (Debian). The directions say that with that distribution, I need to build it from source. When I do, and try to execute the make, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/4.4.34-v7+/build M=/tmp/tmp.tHMTTCom3X/lttng-modules-2.9.0 CONFIG_LTTNG=m CONFIG_LTTNG_CLOCK_PLUGIN_TEST=m modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/lib/modules/4.4.34-v7+/build'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'modules'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/lib/modules/4.4.34-v7+/build'
Makefile:110: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

(It looks to me that there is a rule for that target.)

Has anyone done this, or have any tips or ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the headers for the running kernel, try installing the *raspberrypi-kernel-headers* package :

```
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

Comment: Thanks, @Michael.

Comment: /var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.5.1/build/wrapper/ringbuffer/../../lib/ringbuffer/../../wrapper/ringbuffer/../../lib/ringbuffer/frontend_api.h: In function `lib_ring_buffer_put_cpu':
/var/lib/dkms/lttng-modules/2.5.1/build/wrapper/ringbuffer/../../lib/ringbuffer/../../wrapper/ringbuffer/../../lib/ringbuffer/frontend_api.h:76:2: error: implicit declaration of function `__get_cpu_var' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  __get_cpu_var(lib_ring_buffer_nesting)--;
  ^

Comment: I see you are running a 4.4.34 kernel which is pretty recent with and older lttng-modules 2.5.1, that's not supported. You'll need to get a newer version of lttng, either 2.8 or 2.9. You can rebuild the source packages from debian testing on jessie or build from source.

Comment: When I try to install, I can only seem to get heads/stable-2.5.0; I don't know why.

I was trying to build from source when I ran into the original issue at the start of this thread.

Comment: (meaning, when I use apt-get install, I can't get anything newer than that)

Comment: You'll need to get the source packages from a newer debian release because your kernel is much more recent than the one shipped with a normal jessie system.